# regarding logging.basicconfig in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I once saw the following code segment,

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                level=logging.INFO,
                stream=sys.stdout)
```

What does this `logging.basicConfig` try to do?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> Does basic configuration for the logging system by creating a StreamHandler with a default Formatter and adding it to the root logger.

So by doing it you setup how log messages are going to look (logging format), which of them will be written (logging level), and where to write them (logging stream).